# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow

Tags: workflow

How can you configure a workflow to call an HTTP Web Service request and evaluate the response headers
to determine if the POST to an MVC Controller end-point was a success or failure

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://mysharepointinsight.blogspot.be/2013/05/using-sharepoint-rest-services-from.html) article should guide you through this. Instead of calling the SharePoint REST API, you should then call your custom Web API from your MVC application.

Comment: Great information on posting and love the walkthru and explanations. Still not sure how to get back acknowledgement that the post was succesfull.

Comment: I believe there are two ways to achieve this:
either through response codes (out of the box, see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fbc917e3-99df-435b-ac49-d66408651c98/401-unauthorized-error-when-calling-a-sharepoint-rest-web-service-from-sharepoint-2013-workflow?forum=sharepointgeneral) and [here](http://blog.ctp.com/2014/03/12/updating-list-items-using-sharepoint-2013-workflow-engine/) ). Another way would be to process the response content from the POST request (custom)